# Ignore HTML in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Is there a easy way to tell the update panel not to update a certain element inside of it?

Comment: Why? Why not simply re-render that bit unchanged?

Comment: I am adjusting it via javascript, and unless I also update it on the server side it will not keep the change.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(AsyncPostback); 
function AsyncPostback() { //insert your code here };
```

because your javascript code can not run after one postback. 
 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple UpdatePanels instead of just one. You can work these in around the static HTML content. If, at some point, you will also need the HTML content to be updated, you can also put that inside an UpdatePanel, but set its `UpdateMode` property to `Conditional` so that it only updates when you want it to and not when the others do (which is the default behaviour).